# Unable to start Ruby Thin Command

Tags: ruby, rbenv, thin, dashing

I am trying to run a dashboard written in Ruby using the Dashing framework. However, when I go to run:

`dashing start`

I get this:

```
bundler: failed to load command: thin (/Users/haddad/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/thin)
```

I should note, I did kill the thin process manually by `kill <PID of thin>`

How to fix this or restart that process?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have the `Dashing` framework in your `Gemfile` and ran `bundle install`?